# Grid sorting with nested objects

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can I enable grid sorting with nested object. For example I have the following object which I bind locally to the grid

```
{
    DataId: 1,
    Duration: 4.5,
    Customer: {
        CustomerId: 1,
        Name: 'Foo'
    }
}
```

Now I want to enable sorting for the Name of the Customer (Customer.Name). The parse method didn't worked for me, cause I wrote a custom editortemplate which replace the complete customer with the new selected one.

Comment: Is it client-side sorting your're looking for an answer for?

Comment: @Mads Tjørnelund Toustrup yes, it's all bound to a locally viewmodel